# Mysql: Set column charset

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have an existing table and I want to convert the charset only for one specific column to utf-8.

I know that this command `ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8` does it for the whole table but I'm looking for a column-specific command.

Is there a command for that?

Comment: Please remember to use `utf8mb4`, instead of `utf8`, as MySQL's `utf8` is not UTF8: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Thanks. Am I forced to add the column type (e.g. CHAR(50)) to the command? I mean, the only way to do what I want to do is to redefine the field from scratch?

Comment: not necessary to convert to char.if you have set your datatype to varchar means use this.
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 VARCHAR(M) CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: My question is not about char or varchar but in general, does this command MUST contain the field datatype. I'd expect a command like "ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHARACTER SET utf8", leaving the datatype as it is.

Comment: I noticed that just changing table charset/collation automatically changes the columns charset/collation no need to change individual columns. This happened on MySQL 5.7.19, but as far as I can remember it did not happen locally on MySQL 5.7.18, I add to modify each column as per this answer. I see nothing in the release log about this behaviour.

Comment: I would suggest adding an edit to your answer to explain why it is different from what OP tried, and how that changes things.

Comment: You may also want to set the COLLATION.  [This site](https://www.hellodevops.blog/posts/database-character-sets-and-collations-explained/) explains that `urf8mb4_unicode520_ci` is probably the best general purpose collation.
`ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE urfmb4_unicode_520_ci`

Answer (score 22):

I share that, it can always help...
I modified a database recently; moving from utf8 to utf8mb4; here is the script that allowed me to generate the alters...

Generate SQL commands to alter the tables:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `",`TABLE_NAME`,"` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;") 
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'xxxx';
```

Generate SQL commands to alter each column:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE `",`TABLE_NAME`,"` MODIFY `",`COLUMN_NAME`,"` ",COLUMN_TYPE," CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ",IF(`IS_NULLABLE`='YES', 'NULL', 'NOT NULL')," ",IF(`COLUMN_DEFAULT` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(" DEFAULT '", `COLUMN_DEFAULT`, "'"), ''),";") 
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'xxx' AND `TABLE_NAME` = 'xxxx' AND (`CHARACTER_SET_NAME` IS NOT NULL OR `COLLATION_NAME` IS NOT NULL);
```

Note that for foreign keys and primary keys that make a relationship, you will need to disable foregin key checks before modifying the column

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and enable afterwards.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Not work if you use varchar as a foreign key ! You have to drop the constraint, make the alter and then recreate it.

Comment: Why are you using varchars as foreign keys?

Comment: Personally I do not do it. But I came across several projects where devs use it ...

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!

Comment: is this going to be an online operation or not in mysql version 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

Below one worked for me.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name   
MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```