# Filter django query by unicode characters  or  etc

Tags: mysql, django, utf8mb4

I have a model:

```
class Trophy(models.Model):
    server = models.CharField(max_length=191, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=191, blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    badge = models.CharField(max_length=191)
```

badge - is a field for unicode characters like  or  or  or ☔️ or  etc...

I have three trophies in database:

1. Dragon (badge=)
2. Antiaircrafter (badge=☔️)
3. Diamond player (badge=)

I have not problem to get trophy with badge ☔️:

```
trophy = Trophy.objects.get(badge=u"☔️")
```

But I can't get  or :

```
trophy = Trophy.objects.get(badge=u"")
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Trophy -- it returned 2!
```

And one more thing: I can't see  and  in MySQL Workbench (only "?") untill run:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

Any idea how to work with utf8mb4 in django queries?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database

Comment: What's confusing you about that error? You have two trophies with that badge. You can use `filter` instead of `get` to return them both.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, I have one object with , one with  and one with ☔️

Comment: One question mark or 4?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding OPTIONS for db settings in django settings.py:

```
'OPTIONS': {
     'charset': 'utf8mb4',
     'use_unicode': True,
     'init_command': "SET NAMES utf8mb4;",
 }
```

And create db with command

```
CREATE DATABASE feofun_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```