# how filter unicode textfield django

Tags: django, unicode, filter

i have a model as bellow

```
class CommentOfPost(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField()
```

comment_text data is unicode('utf-8') looklike 'سلام علیکم' and 'Хороший результат!'

some data is 'السلام علیک' and 'سلام علیکم' and 'اسلامی' and 'مرحبا سلام علیک'

i want filter looklike

`CommentOfPost.objects.filter(comment_text_contains='سلام')`

and result just be:

`queryset<'سلام علیکم','مرحبا سلام علیک'>`

not be:

`queryset< 'سلام علیکم' , 'اسلامی' , 'مرحبا سلام علیک','السلام علیک' >`

another word i want regex filter in unicode text

NOTE:

i try this:

```
comments = CommentOfPost.objects.filter(comment_text__iregex=r'\b{}\b'.format(u'سلام'))
```

but when i use regex or iregex not return any unicode results

Comment: do you use `utf8mb4`?

Comment: please, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234897/filter-django-query-by-unicode-characters-or-etc

Comment: Try using a word boundary in your regular expression