# Emoji icon not insert in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to insert emoji icon to my mqsql. but it insert like `í ½í¸`.

I changed my Database CHARACTER SET `utf8mb4` and I changed my table CHARACTER SET `utf8mb4` and collate to `utf8mb4_general_ci` or `utf8mb4_bin`.

but still not stored emoji icon. im using mysql query browser.

Im getting emoji icon from here

```
https://emojipedia.org/smiling-face-with-open-mouth-and-smiling-eyes/
```

how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

- change database default collation to `utf8mb4`
- change table collation as `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`
- change the emoji column collation to `utf8mb4_bin`

if possible set  characterset in dbconnection to `utf8mb4` 
`$database_connection->set_charset("utf8mb4");`

refer : [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)