# How to save emoji in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, emoji

I need to save to the database emoji. I read that I need a table type utf8mb4(utf8mb4_general_ci).

I create a table:

[image]

Make a request:

[image]

Res:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to add emoji?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database here is your answer.
Before asking you should research first

Comment: `utf8mb4` is necessary for Emoji.