# Saving another language data

Tags: mysql, sql, angularjs, collation

How to save a text in another language with emoticons into sql database and use it to display on angularJS?

Backend language used is php and frontend is AngularJS.
Database mySQL

Comment: have a column with nvarchar datatype and save all the unicode data into that column

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. Do you have any backend language or service in mind?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465494/6201829

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), as asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` directly (or indirectly) on all column definitions that expect to have Emoji.

You must connect with `utf8mb4` or execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4` after connecting.

If you get question marks, Mojibake, etc instead of Emoji, [*this Q&A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) may tell you what you failed to do.