# Not able to store emojis on a utf8mb mysql table

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, emoji

Having this table using mysql 5.7:

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

When I try to insert some emojis:

```
INSERT INTO `emails` (`from_address`, `subject`) VALUES (1, 'AB  C‍D')
```

I receive:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x80B ...' for column 'subject' at row 1
```

Why? if i'm using utfmb?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)

Comment: Relevant is the third answer on the linked question with `SET NAMES utf8mb4`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0bbce/1

Answer (score 2):

Is your connection also utf8mb4? Detailed explanation of this can be found at: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4