# Save emoji to db and show it in a DIV Ionic 3

Tags: mysql, ionic-framework

I have an app that saves TODO's but when I type a given emoji, it goes as `????`. Searched everywhere but didn't find any solution that may help me.

I'm using `Ionic` and `MySql` to store the data. Using `utf8mb4_bin` for the table collation.

I've done a test with notifications and it appears correctly at the notification when app closed but when I open the app it shows only `????` And in the db it is being saved as `????` too.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)