# Change charset for MySql

Tags: mysql, django

I am using MySql along with Django. I am trying to save an object containing an emoji. I have changed the charset for the table using the following commands

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and when I use the command

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

for seeing the columns I get the following output -

```
Field: unit_text
      Type: longtext
 Collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      Null: YES
       Key: 
   Default: NULL
     Extra: 
Privileges: select,insert,update,references
   Comment:
```

Here coalition is utf8mb4_unicode_ci but still, when I try to save the object I get this error -

```
OperationalError "Incorrect string value"
```

Please let me know what I should do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store Emoji Character in My SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database)

Comment: You know that collation character set only plays a role when ordering result sets or comparing values like with < or >, right? You need to set the character set on your session (connection). Try issuing `SET NAMES 'utf8'` once the connection is established.

Comment: i used set names, it didn't work, please let me know what else I can try