# Yii 2 not rendering emojis from mysql database

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii 2 app and emojis are not rendering when I grab data from the database. It is storing inside my database fine as an emoji, but not in my view. It's returning as a ? character.

In my head I have

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Am I missing something?

**SOLUTION**

Go into your db config file (where you set up your db name and password) and change charset to utf8mb4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-my-sql-database

Comment: check if you can make it work using `utf8mb4` as connection `charset` in the database configuration inthe `config/main.php`

Comment: Dude thank you. This worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the collation of the connection to `utf8mb4` in your config file under the database component configuration like below

```
'db'=>[
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection' ,
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_name' ,
    'username' => 'username' ,
    'password' => 'password' ,
    'charset'=>'utf8mb4'
]
```

or change the table collation configuration in the database

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```