# Outputting UTF-8 from ContentEditable Element

Tags: php, html, forms, contenteditable

Inside a form, I have a `contenteditable` `div`. When the `div` loses focus, its contents are transferred (HTML included) to a hidden text `input`. Here is the simplified HTML:

```
<div contenteditable id="editable"></div>
<input class="hidden" id="content" />
```

This `content` field has its contents uploaded to a database, later to be used on a blog. The problem is that the either the `contenteditable` `div` or the `input` itself appear to encode their contents as ASCII rather than UTF-8, resulting in unrecognised characters in my database (such as "ð¡" instead of "").

I have added the following PHP header information to the top of my form page:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

And also the following in the `head` section of every page on the site:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I also use a PHP function to "utf8ize" all of the `$_POST`ed fields.

... to no avail.

Comment: Most probably its the issue with the db charset , might want to try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465494/2693543

Comment: @Shobi Put this as an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Sure. Kindly check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save emojis in your database, your database charset should be `utf8mb4`.

1. for that reason, you will have to change database collation first.

   `ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_bin;`
2. then you will have to change the existing tables charset

   `` ALTER TABLE `Tablename` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin ``

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the Encoding from your .html file. You can find it out over Notepad++ under "Encoding"

Comment: Nearly... the issue was with my database encoding.