# Clean emoji in input

Tags: php, utf-8, user-input, emoji

How can I clean my form inputs for characters like emojis? For example, when I post a paragraph in a text area with an emoji like this , a Record does not gets inserted to database. I can not change my database table to utf8mb. It is utf8 right now. I have tried the following functions but none of them works.

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);
$str = utf8_encode($str);
$str = mb_convert_encoding ($str, "UTF-8");
$str = htmlspecialchars ($str);
$str = htmlspecialchars ($str, ENT_SUBSTITUTE, 'UTF-8');
$str = htmlspecialchars ($str, ENT_SUBSTITUTE);
```

json_encode($str) does change emoji to something like "\UXXXX" but it wraps all inputs in double-quotes and I have to decode it for every input.

To be clear if someone inputs "hello world " I want to save one of the following to the database: 
hello world or 
hello world :-) or 
hello world :smile:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iconv`: the UCS2 character set supports the only the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) -- just like mysql's version of "utf8" -- so doing a roundtrip through UCS2 will drop all emojis while preserving most characters from most modern languages.

```
$s = "hello world ";
$s = iconv("ucs2", "utf8", iconv("utf8", "ucs2//IGNORE", $s))
var_dump($s); // string(12) "hello world "
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, your database character set needs to be `utf8mb4`.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/13174611) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465494/13174611) for more information.