# Some unicode icons are not saved and displayed correct

Tags: html, css, mysql, utf-8, icons

I'am trying to add unicode icons to my website SEO title/meta and for some reason it will not accept some icons. My site is UTF-8. Im saving it in my database as `utf8_general_ci`.

When i add the icon  it will return as ????
https://emojipedia.org/heavy-dollar-sign/

When I add the icon ✔️ it will add the ✔️ in the title.
https://emojipedia.org/check-mark/

Is there an reason for this or is this normal?

Comment: Good pointer, did see that if i change the type to BLOB it will save the icons. Thanks

Comment: I reopened this question because the main Answers in the proposed dup ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database ) failed to suggest the one thing that was needed to fix the problem.

Comment: Changing to `BLOB`, though it will work, is simply sweeping the problem under the rug.  It is solvable with `TEXT` and `utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"✔️" is a 3-byte Emoji; "" takes 4 bytes.  So the problem is that `CHARACTER SET utf8` needs to be changed to `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

The solution is to either

- Provide `utf8mb4` in the connection parameters`. This action varies with the client (Java/PHP/...).
- Add `SET NAMES utf8mb4` to the code right after connecting.

If these are not specific enough, search for where you have `utf8` and it could be `utf8mb4`.  (Note:  I am not saying `UTF-8`, which is the non-MySQL equivalent of `utf8mb4`.)

More discussion:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Technically the checkmark takes 6 bytes -- two 3-byte characters: hex E29C94 EFB88F.  So it worked fine with `utf8`.  However the dollar sign needs 4 bytes: F09F92B2, so it could not be represented in utf8, only in utf8mb4.  The failure was shown via 4 question marks.

Comment: With an exciting databse what will be te effect of issues when switching van utf8 to uft8mb4?

Comment: @user759235 - Both sides of a `JOIN` should have the same charset and collation.  Otherwise, not much impact.