# Execute a query right after database creation

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, collation

So my question is duplicate or mundane but i really can use some help here. I want to store emojis and some special characters in specific columns of 3 tables. My application is a workflow engine [Processmaker](https://www.processmaker.com/) running inside docker. This application talks with mysql server running as another docker container.

To solve the issue i have followed below links and did the changes too but all in vain. The databases are created dynamically.

1. [How to store Emoji Character in MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database)
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153720/mysql-unable-to-store-emoji-in-utf8mb4-collation

Please correct me if i am wrong.
Even if i want to save emoji into 3 tables i have to change the collation and charset of :

1. The Database.
2. Associated tables in which i want to store emojis.
3. Associated columns of those tables which would hold those emoji characters.

I achieve above steps (1-3) by running mysql queries after database creation, like so :

```
    ALTER DATABASE database CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 

    ALTER TABLE table_one CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    ALTER TABLE table_one CHANGE column_one column_one mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; 
    ALTER TABLE table_two CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    ALTER TABLE table_two CHANGE column_two column_two mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
    SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

for changing the collation and charset i also tried the approach of configuring it in my.cnf as such ( to achieve step 1 - step 2 ) :

```
    [mysqld]
    character-set-server = utf8mb4
    collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
    character-set-client-handshake = FALSE

    [mysql]
    default-character-set = utf8mb4


    [client]
    default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

All of above steps doesn't seem to work. Also the mysql server can have lot of databases which are created dynamically.
Right after the database creation i run below query :

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`

and i get this result :
[image: some collation and charset info]

My sql client also uses utf8mb4 charset and collation as utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
Since there could be hundreds of databases and it isn't possible for me to go and run these queries manually for each of them

So i was thinking if i can run some queries right after database creation OR Is there a way to do it ?

Mysql server version - 5.6.48 running in docker. If you need further info kindly let me know.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`my.cnf` (and other global settings) feed into *`GLOBAL VARIABLES`*.

When you connect to the database, defaults are taken from `GLOBAL VARIABLES`.  Any parameters on the *connection* override them.  (Example:  Most programming language clients allow you to provide `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` during the establishment of the connection.)

An alternative to establishing the values at the time of connecting is to run this right after connecting:

```
 SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

`SHOW VARIABLES` displays the settings provided *when you logged in*, plus any *session* changes made since then.

While you are connected, `SET GLOBAL VARIABLES` will change the `GLOBALs`, *but not the `SESSIONs`*.

While you are connected, `SET SESSION VARIABLES` will change the `SESSION` values, *but will be lost at logout*.

This `my.cnf` setting is both good and bad; I recommend avoiding it:

```
init_command = SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

It says to run that `SET` in any session that is starting up.  *But, 'root' skips this step!*  (That is probably to allow root to connect without having to fix my.cnf.)

You must make sure the client is encoding things with UTF-8.  The details vary widely.  Fortunately, clients are moving that direction; but they are not all there yet.

So...

**Plan A**

- Set up my.cnf with the 3 char* values and (optionally, the one collation).
- Don't bother with anything on `CREATEs`.  (Doing so could override my.cnf)
- But be sure to create the database, then the table.  (If you already had a database or table in the system with the 'wrong' charset, it will override my.cnf.)

**Plan B**  (This is overkill, but safe.)

- Always establish the charset when connecting (via either connection parameters or `SET NAMES`)
- Always explicitly specify charset on `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE`.

**Miscellany**

A further note:  Stored Routines take on the charset for the *database*.

`CHARACTER SET` controls encoding.  That is critical for Emojy; `utf8mb4` is the only solution.

`COLLATION` deals with ordering and deciding whether one emoji is "equal to" another.  This is rarely an issue for Emoji, but is a big deal for text.  For text it controls case folding (is "A"="a") and accent stripping, plus other issues.

If the tables are created with utf8mb4, there is no need for `ALTER TABLE`.  And if there is no explicit `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` on the table definition, it will inherit from the `CREATE DATABASE`, etc.

If something goes wrong, [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) may help you figure out where things went wrong.

This is a roadmap on which `ALTER` is needed to repair a table: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases

`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is a quite old collation.  `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` is better.  MySQL 8.0 has an even newer one.

My point is that you should not have to do any `ALTERs` *if* things are initialized "correctly".  Clearly, since "latin1" show in that screen shot, things were not set up "correctly".

The inheritance hierarchy is:

1. my.cnf and mysqld args (sets `GLOBAL VARIABLES`)
2. connect (Copies `GLOBAL` to `SESSION`, then overrides with connection parameters)
   3.`SET NAMES` (overrides 3 `SESSION VARIABLES`)
3. `CREATE DATABASE` (Establish inheritable defaults for the database)
4. `CREATE TABLE` (Establish inheritable defaults for the table)
5. Attributes on column definitions.

Comment: Thanks a ton @rick-james. This information is better than most answers for this problem.
Can you help me identify somepoints :
for database character-set-server and collation-server can be set using my.cnf

Is it possible that i can set character_set_database and collation_database too from my.cnf ?

Comment: @PawanSaxena - Since you are using Docker, it should be easy enough to experiment.  Alas, even after a decade of chasing charset issues, I cannot explain what each of the 7 my.cnf `character_set_%` settings does.  3 of them are dynamically settable by `SET NAMES`.  Those 3 seem to be necessary and sufficient seem to handle the issues discussed here.  (The other 4 deal with system tables, filesystem, etc.)

Comment: Thanks @rick-james.
I got it figured out. I also found this additional piece of info. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-server.html

Comment: @PawanSaxena - That page says that the "database" defaults come from the "server" variables, not the "database" variables.  Confusing.

Comment: For me too it was confusing, but i am reading through next pages now.