# Emojis storing as ? in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, character-encoding, emoji

I'm using wordpress as CMS, Plesk is host and I got a question. I understand that for the database to store emojis, the charset should be changed to utf8mb4.

1. Where do I change it?
2. Is there any global setting so that every site uses the new utf8mb4?
3. And how do I change it to an existing database which has emojis stored already?

Because it really hurts when migrating to new servers. All the emojis then appear as ? when importing database.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1, change your database's default charset:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

if the db is not created yet, create it with correct encodings:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE = 
utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Step 2, set charset when creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

or alter table

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY field_name TEXT CHARSET utf8mb4;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database)