# Inserting Unicode emojis  in MariaDB's MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

I already changed my table and column collation to `utf8mb4_bin`.
When making the connection, I passed the `utf8` `charset` value `mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="****", database="dbname", charset='utf8')`
I even added the following statement right after opening the connection:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8;")
mydb.commit()
```

It only works partially. For example, this emoji is displayed in the table as you see it here: ⚡️

But these (a few examples):       are displayed in table as ???? (4 question marks).

What did I forget to set or change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database

Comment: Does the utf8 charset differ from utf8mb4? The lightning bolt in the BMP; the smiley face is not in the BMP and requires 4 bytes to encode in UTF-8. (And that is indeed an issue, per a quick web search — see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql).

Comment: That is, try to use `utf8mb4` in the table *and* connection *and* SET NAMES.

Comment: Thank you guys, setting `charset='utf8mb4'` in `mysql.connector.connect()` fixed it. I don't know why I only had `utf8`. I was able to also remove `mycursor.execute("SET NAMES utf8mb4;")` as it was redundant.

Comment: Just a quick thought: mysql-connector doesn't let me pass `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as charset parameter when setting up connection. If it did, would using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` be better than `utf8mb4`?

Comment: UTF-8 (well, when done correctly) is UTF-8 (an encoding of Unicode to bytes). The collation in the table *also* affects ordering and comparing (such as Case-Insensitive); however it has no effect on the encoding (the UTF-8 byte representation, when done correctly).