# Doctrine DBAL Driver Exception when sending e-mails

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Am facing an exception when sending e-mails in Shopware 6.4.19.0:

```
(Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\DriverException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO enqueue (id, published_at, body, headers, properties, priority, queue, redelivered, delivery_id, redeliver_after) ...
...
(PDOException(code: 22007): SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\x89 B...' for column `db_21849_01`.`enqueue`.`body` at row 1 at /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117)"} []
```

It is thrown for e-mails including emojis.
It has not happened with 6.4.18.1.

What might cause it and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you already sent emails including emojis in 6.4.18.1? Shopware should not change the charset during an update.. was anything else change with the database?

Comment: With the DB's default collation being `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` it's either been "something" in the migration in-between the two versions ...

or

... something in step 2 at https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/message-queue-and-scheduled-tasks added / edited the table.

Comment: But as the change of the collation has fixed the issue, see answer below, I will not follow-up on the suspects.

Answer (score 1):

Check the collation and character set of your database. For storing Emojis you need at least a `mb4` character set.

[How to store Emoji Character in MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database)

Comment: It has been the collation, but not for the DB. Only the "enqueue" table was affected.

Comment: Am lacking "reputation" to vote for this as being the correct answer.
So here comes a thumbs up instead 