# pandas to_sql giving UnicodeEncodeError for table with JSON column

Tags: python, mysql, json, pandas, sqlalchemy

Preface: I am aware of similar questions on this topic, and have attempted their solutions to no avail.

I'm creating a python script to grab a JSON file from an ftp address, convert it to a Pandas dataframe, and then send it to MySQL to populate a table. I've encountered an issue with Pandas.to_sql, however. The error is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xd1' in position 87: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
cnx = create_engine('mysql://username:password@192.168.1.11/database?charset=utf8',encoding='utf-8')

sl1 = pd.read_json('ftp://username:password@ftp.address.com/directory/sailings_cel.txt')
sl1 = pd.json_normalize(sl1["Dataset"])

sl1.to_sql(name='celsailingtemp',con=cnx,if_exists='append',index=True)
```

Potentially helpful information:

- I've tried multiple permutations of ensuring that encoding is set to utf-8 in the create_engine statement, as per similar questions on StackOverflow.
- The JSON file is provided on the FTP server with the .txt extension, but I think that should be OK since it's handled fine by read_json and json_normalize..
- According to https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?unicodeinhtml=hex, it looks like xd1 could be the Ñ character. Sure enough, the offending character can be found in the itinerary column.
- Speaking of columns, the JSON data structure is shown below. Setting the json_normalize level to "Dataset" relegates the nested "itinerary" column to a long string, which is fine by me. I've set that column's type to "JSON" on the mysql end.
  [image: JSON overview]
  [image: Supporting evidence of "capital N with tilde" being the offending character]
- The MySQL table structure looks like this:
  [image: MySQL Table Structure]
- I probably could simply excise the itinerary column, but the core encoding issue wouldn't be solved and I want to do this right.

Any guidance on this issue would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/pythondir/debug.py", line 14, in <module>
    sl1.to_sql(name='celsailingtemp',con=cnx,if_exists='append',index=True)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2602, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 589, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1398, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 830, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 747, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1014, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1127, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1515, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1257, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mysql\mysqldb.py", line 148, in do_executemany
    rowcount = cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 230, in executemany
    return self._do_execute_many(
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 255, in _do_execute_many
    v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 110, in _escape_args
    ret = tuple(literal(ensure_bytes(arg)) for arg in args)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 110, in <genexpr>
    ret = tuple(literal(ensure_bytes(arg)) for arg in args)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 286, in literal
    s = self._tuple_literal(o)
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 269, in _tuple_literal
    return b"(%s)" % (b",".join(map(self.literal, t)))
  File "C:\pythondir\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 288, in literal
    s = self.escape(o, self.encoders)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xd1' in position 87: ordinal not in range(128)
```

JSON Snippet including offending character:

```
{
    "Table": "Cruise Sailing - Celebrity Cruises (CEL)",
    "Number_of_CEL_sailings": 1032,
    "Dataset": [
      {
        "SailingID": "117624",
        "SailingPlanID": "70561",
        "SailingPlanCode": "07G019",
        "MarketName": "[United States, Canada, United Kingdom, Ireland, Australia, Spain, German, Portugal, Switzerland, New Zealand, United Arab Emirates, Mexico]",
        "MarketNameList": [
          "United States",
          "Canada",
          "United Kingdom",
          "Ireland",
          "Australia",
          "Spain",
          "German",
          "Portugal",
          "Switzerland",
          "New Zealand",
          "United Arab Emirates",
          "Mexico"
        ],
        "ShipID": "1373927",
        "ShipName": "Celebrity Flora",
        "DepartureDate": "2020-08-23",
        "Duration": "7",
        "PackageID": "FL07G019",
        "SailingName": "7 NIGHT GALAPAGOS INNER LOOP",
        "DestinationID": "615",
        "DeparturePortCode": "BAL",
        "DeparturePortID": "1203",
        "ReturnPortCode": "BAL",
        "ReturnPortID": "1203",
        "PackageTypeID": "0",
        "TourOnly": "no",
        "Segment": "no",
        "Itinerary": [
          {
            "DayNumber": 1,
            "PortID": "1203",
            "PortCode": "BAL",
            "Description": "BALTRA (GALAPAGOS)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "--",
            "DepartureTime": "2:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 1,
            "PortID": "3781",
            "PortCode": "DAP",
            "Description": "DAPHNE ISLAND",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "5:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "6:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 2,
            "PortID": "1212",
            "PortCode": "RAB",
            "Description": "RABIDA  (GALAPAGOS)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "3:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "7:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 2,
            "PortID": "1211",
            "PortCode": "PGA",
            "Description": "EGAS PORT",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "12:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 2,
            "PortID": "1212",
            "PortCode": "RAB",
            "Description": "RABIDA  (GALAPAGOS)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "3:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "7:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 3,
            "PortID": "1656",
            "PortCode": "EBI",
            "Description": "ELIZABETH BAY",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "12:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 3,
            "PortID": "1209",
            "PortCode": "CET",
            "Description": "TAGUS COVE (ISABELLA)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "3:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "7:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 4,
            "PortID": "1211",
            "PortCode": "SLV",
            "Description": "SULLIVAN BAY (SANTIAGO)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "12:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 4,
            "PortID": "1207",
            "PortCode": "BAR",
            "Description": "BARTOLOME ISLAND",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "1:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "7:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 5,
            "PortID": "1208",
            "PortCode": "LSB",
            "Description": "LAS BACHAS -  (SANTA CRUZ)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "12:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 5,
            "PortID": "1204",
            "PortCode": "NSY",
            "Description": "NORTH SEYMOUR ISLAND",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "1:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "9:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 6,
            "PortID": "6167",
            "PortCode": "SCC",
            "Description": "PUERTO BAQUERIZO (CRISTOBAL)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "12:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 6,
            "PortID": "6168",
            "PortCode": "PSC",
            "Description": "PUNTA PITT (SAN CRISTOBAL)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "3:30 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "6:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 7,
            "PortID": "1536",
            "PortCode": "PTA",
            "Description": "PUERTO AYORA (SANTA CRUZ)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "7:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 8,
            "PortID": "1203",
            "PortCode": "BAL",
            "Description": "BALTRA (GALAPAGOS)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "--"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "SailingID": "117625",
        "SailingPlanID": "70560",
        "SailingPlanCode": "07G020",
        "MarketName": "[United States, Canada, United Kingdom, Ireland, Australia, Spain, German, Portugal, Switzerland, New Zealand, United Arab Emirates, Mexico]",
        "MarketNameList": [
          "United States",
          "Canada",
          "United Kingdom",
          "Ireland",
          "Australia",
          "Spain",
          "German",
          "Portugal",
          "Switzerland",
          "New Zealand",
          "United Arab Emirates",
          "Mexico"
        ],
        "ShipID": "1373927",
        "ShipName": "Celebrity Flora",
        "DepartureDate": "2020-08-30",
        "Duration": "7",
        "PackageID": "FL07G020",
        "SailingName": "7 NIGHT GALAPAGOS OUTER LOOP",
        "DestinationID": "615",
        "DeparturePortCode": "BAL",
        "DeparturePortID": "1203",
        "ReturnPortCode": "BAL",
        "ReturnPortID": "1203",
        "PackageTypeID": "0",
        "TourOnly": "no",
        "Segment": "no",
        "Itinerary": [
          {
            "DayNumber": 1,
            "PortID": "1203",
            "PortCode": "BAL",
            "Description": "BALTRA (GALAPAGOS)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "--",
            "DepartureTime": "2:30 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 1,
            "PortID": "3781",
            "PortCode": "DAP",
            "Description": "DAPHNE ISLAND",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "5:00 PM",
            "DepartureTime": "6:00 PM"
          },
          {
            "DayNumber": 2,
            "PortID": "3020",
            "PortCode": "GRB",
            "Description": "GARDNER BAY (ESPAÑOLA)",
            "Language": "en_US",
            "ArrivalTime": "7:00 AM",
            "DepartureTime": "2:00 PM"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

DDL for celsailingtemp:

```
CREATE TABLE `celsailingtemp` (
  `index` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sailingplanid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sailingid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sailingplancode` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketname` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `marketnamelist` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipname` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `departuredate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packageid` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sailingname` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `destinationid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departureportcode` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `departureportid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `returnportcode` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `returnportid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `packagetypeid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `touronly` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `segment` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `itinerary` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`index`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_UNIQUE` (`index`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: You made a big effort of adding a lot of detail (which is really good), but you managed to leave out the *most important part*: The traceback. In the beginning you only give the last line of the tracebace, but not the full trace. Without it it's hard to track down the issue. Especially because your question does not contain an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I went ahead and added the full traceback; as for the MCVE, I'm not sure what more I can provide without giving the login for my private FTP address or SQL database, since the code I provided is in its entirety.

Comment:  I had another look and unfortunately the TB does not give a lot more info. Can you post a section of the JSON file with the problematic byte? And maybe the just the DDL of your table? I'm not really keen on typing this off from a screenshot. That way I should be able to repro it and give it another shot.

Comment: I've added the JSON snippet (including Ñ) and the DDL for the table in MySQL. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Having some data to help reproduce this helped a LOT and I got to the same conclusion as Gord Thompson below. Alas he was quicker than me in finding a solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> json_normalize level … relegates the nested "itinerary" column to a long string

Actually no, it doesn't. The column contains a list (or perhaps a Series object) and that was confusing the DBAPI driver. To get it working I had to do this:

```py
sl1 = pd.read_json(r"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\sailing.json")
sl1 = pd.json_normalize(sl1["Dataset"])
sl1["MarketName"] = sl1["MarketName"].map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
sl1["MarketNameList"] = sl1["MarketNameList"].map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))
sl1["Itinerary"] = sl1["Itinerary"].map(lambda x: json.dumps(x))

sl1.to_sql(name="celsailingtemp", con=cnx, if_exists="append", index=True)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! So if I'm reading this correctly, this essentially formats the problem columns as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think your ftp transfer by ascii. Set ftp to use binary mode.

```
sl1 = pd.read_json('ftp://username:password@ftp.address.com/directory/sailings_cel.txt;type=I')
```

I saw your traceback, it seems python encoding problem, not MySQL. Set use utf-8.

1. python encoding
   Set python encoding before execute.

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

2. OS encoding
   confirm utf-8 encoding type, execute `locale -a` command.

```
# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

if you have `C.UTF-8`, set `C.UTF-8`.

```
export LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to change anything. I added a full traceback to my original post, if that helps!

Comment: I wrote extra answer, on the premise you use linux os.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can [change a column's charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781886/mysql-set-column-charset) in your database, which should make your code run fine.

Incidentally, another way to handle such issues is to recreate a subset of your data as a [fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com) and play with it there.